# How to use generated OpenAPI client inside React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, openapi, openapi-generator

I have generated my API client with `openapi-generator-cli generate -i https://linktomybackendswagger/swagger.json -g typescript-axios -o src/components/api --additional-properties=supportsES6=true`

Now I have all the files inside my project but I have no clue how to implement this.
How do I instantiate the API? Where do I configure the access token to be used? How do I know each method name for an endpoint?

After 2 hours of googling I can't seem to find a documentation for what seems like the most basic setup questions. Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out a way that I think is clean that I will document here for others that are going down the same path, which is:

- Using an API that is using `Authorization: Bearer <Token here>`
- Created the client with `openapi-generator-cli` using `-g typescript-axios`
- Using OAS3

Let's say you have an endpoint called `UserPolicies`. After generating the code via CLI each endpoint will have its own class inside the generated file `api.ts` with the name extended like so `UserPoliciesApi`.

For using that endpoint the following setup is required.

Example: Inside `UserPolicyList.tsx`:

```
import { UserPoliciesApi } from './components/api/api';
import { Configuration } from './components/api/configuration';

const openapiConfig = new Configuration();
  openapiConfig.baseOptions = {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + cookies.access_token },
  };
const openapi = new UserPoliciesApi(openapiConfig);
```

Let's assume you want to make a GET call for `api/Policies` you can do so with:

```
openapi.userPoliciesGetPolicies.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Now, what I found inconvenient with this design is the boilerplate code necessary for making one simple api call. I wanted to be able to simply do one import and already have the `access_token` setup.

So I created a wrapper class like this `MyApi.tsx`:

```
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { Configuration } from './components/api/configuration';

class MyApi {
  private cookies: Cookies;

  constructor() {
    this.cookies = new Cookies();
  }

  private accessToken = () => {
    return this.cookies.get('access_token');
  };

  private configuration = () => {
    const openapiConfig = new Configuration();
    openapiConfig.baseOptions = {
      headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken() },
    };
    return openapiConfig;
  };

  public userPoliciesApi = () => {
    const api = new UserPoliciesApi(this.configuration());
    return api;
  };
}

export default MyApi.tsx;
```

Now I you can easily replace the boilerplate and call with this:

Inside `UserPolicyList.tsx`:

```
import { MyApi } from './components/myapi/MyApi.tsx';

const api = new MyApi();
const userPoliciesApi = api.userPoliciesApi();

userPoliciesApi.userPoliciesGetPolicies.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```